# Python mysql connector with multiple statements

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I'm trying to run a SQL query through mysql.connector that requires a SET command in order to query a specific table:

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd   

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host=ip,
                              port=port,
                              user=user,
                              passwd=pwd,
                              database="")
sql="""SET variable='Test'; 
       SELECT * FROM table  """

df = pd.read_sql(sql, cnx)
```

when I run this I get the error "Use multi=True when executing multiple statements".  But where do I put multi=True?

Comment: Possibly pd.read_sql? That seems to be the line that'll raise this error.

Answer (score 1):

after many hours of experimenting, i figured out how do to this.  forgive me if this is not the most succinct way, but the best i could come up with-

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd   

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host=ip,
                              port=port,
                              user=user,
                              passwd=pwd,
                              database="")
sql1="SET variable='Test';" 

sql2="""SELECT * FROM table  """

cursor=cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql1)
cursor.close()

df = pd.read_sql(sql2, cnx)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the parameters as a dictionary into the `params` argument should do the trick, documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html):

```
pd.read_sql(sql, cnx, params={'multi': True})
```

The parameters are passed to the underlying database driver.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I get the same error even when passing the params as you suggest